# Byte Offsets as Unique Ordering Identifiers for Rows in MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

A task that I have is to process the records of a large file and output it preserving the order. There's no way to extract an order from any field in a line, so I tried to use  byte offsets from `TextInputFormat` for these purposes, but faced an issue that the number of distinct  lines is not the same as number of distinct offsets. Here is how my code look like:

Mapper:

```
public void map(LongWritable offset, Text text, Context ctx) {
    ctx.getCounter(Main.COUNTERS.DISTINCT_LINES).increment(1l);
    ctx.write(offset, processLine(text.toString()));
}
```

Reducer:

```
public void reduce(LongWritable offset, Iterable<Text> texts, Context ctx) {
    ctx.getCounter(Main.COUNTERS.DISTINCT_OFFSETS).increment(1l);

    for(Text txt : texts) ctx.write(txt, NullWritable.get());
}
```

It appears that I got number of distinct lines greater than number of distinct offsets.

What's more confusing, after printing offsets that are associated with multiple lines, offset `0` is not in this list, that reject hypothesis that for each split offset starts from `0`.

Could anybody explain this behavior?

Comment: How big is your file? so we can estimate the number of splits. Also, can you reproduce the same results reliably on every run of the job? Theoretically, if a mapper job fails in the middle and is retried, your Distinct Lines counter will count more lines than you have in your original file.

Comment: It's not that big, it's around 400MB, but it's compressed in bz2 (without compression it's around 9GB). What I've noticed that if the file is decompressed this problem disappears... And, yes, I could reproduce it on EMR with any number of working nodes.